# csh scripting for password authorisation of user

Tags: linux, csh

I'm trying to write a professional program to accept and process input via a Menu based system. The program should have no command line arguments. it will be writen in csh script called TaskMenu. This shell script will:

1. ask for a password from the user.
   a. If the password is not correct, the system will exit
   with an appropriate error message.
2. display a text menu and then get a response from the user.
3. process the user input and redisplay the text menu
   until the user wants to quit.

Comment: P.S. i dont know how to write it out in csh script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read a password, turn echo off, read the password, then re-enable echo. csh:

```
stty -echo 
echo -n "Enter password: "
set password = $<
stty echo
```

To create a menu, just echo the choices to the screen, then 
read a value back. csh:

```
echo 1 first item
echo 2 second item
echo 3 third ...
echo -n "Enter Choice: "
set choice = $<
```

These same two tasks in bash are:

Read password:

```
echo -n "Enter password: "
read -s password
```

Make menu:

```
select choice in "first item" "second item" "third..." do
test -n "$choice" && break; 
done
```

Notice how reading a password and making a menu are built-in to bash. In addition to being easier, some common things done in scripting are impossible in csh.  Csh is not designed as a scripting language.  It is much easier to use Bash, Python, Ruby, Perl or even the lowly */bin/sh* for scripting anything over a few lines.

That said, here is a full csh script showing the password and menu methods:

```
#! /bin/csh

set PW="ok"

### Read Password
echo -n "enter passwd: "
stty -echo
set passwd = $<
stty echo

if ( "$passwd" == "$PW" ) then
        echo Allrighty then!
else
    echo "Try again. Use '${PW}'."
    exit 1
endif


### Menu
@ i = 1
set items = (one two three four five six seven)
foreach item ( $items[*] ) 
    echo "${i}) $item"
    @ i = $i + 1
end
set choice = 0
while ( $choice < 1 || $choice > $#items )
    echo -n "Select: "
    set choice = $<
end
echo "You chose ${choice}: $items[$choice]"
```

**Notes**

> Though popular for interactive use
>   because of its many innovative
>   features, csh has never been as
>   popular for scripting[1]

[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell#Criticism) [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell#Criticism)

Answer (score 1):

Q: Why in the heck would anybody want to use csh in a bash world ;)  csh is Soooo 1985 ;)